# Callbacks for SeekBar implementation in Android

Tags: android, callback, seekbar

The following callbacks are implemented for the seekbar:

```
void onProgressChanged(Seekbar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch);

void onStartTrackingTouch(Seekbar seekBar);

void onStopTrackingTouch(Seekbar seekBar);
```

1. But what callback is received when OK is pressed on the seekbar?
2. onStartTrackingTouch() is received when the user has just started to move the seekbar.
   onStopTrackingTouch() is received when user has finished moving the seekbar. 
   Am i correct in these definitions or are these two callbacks for something else?

Could someone help with these two queries?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean

> But what callback is received when OK is pressed on the seekbar?

Do you have a ok button that should implement something? If so you can use a integer value to save the progress when the progress is changed and then when you press the ok button you can execute whatever you want. Look at this example

```
    seekerSpacing.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            doSomethingAfterTracking();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            doSomethingWhenTrackingStarts();
        }

        /**
        * seekBar   The SeekBar whose progress has changed
        * progress  The current progress level. This will be in the range 0..max where max was set by setMax(int). (The default value for max is 100.)
        * fromUser  True if the progress change was initiated by the user.
        */
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            setMyCurrentProgress(progress);
            doSomeOtherMethodIfRequired();
        }
    });
```

You can have a look at the Android [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html) for the correct explanations. But here is a quick summary.

The `onStartTrackingTouch` method is invoked as soon as you touch the seekbar. This method will always be invoked when you touch the seekbar slider

The `onStopTrackingTouch` method is invoked as soon as you let go of the seekbar. This method will always be invoked when you let go of the seekbar slider.

The `onProgressChanged` method is invoked as soon as the progress of the seekbar is changed. This method will only be invoked when the progress changes

Comment: the seekbar dialog has OK button in it also. So something should be received as a callback when user presses the OK button. HOw do i implement that? I mean i need  to know when the user has presses OK button

Comment: Can you post the code on how you create your seekbar and also where you implement the setOnSeekBarChangeListener